# Not getting any kind of output

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isprime(int n)
{
    int i,flag=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if((n%i)==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1||n==1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
int main()
{
    int ul,ll;
    cin>>ll>>ul;
    for(int i=ll;i<=ul;i++)
    {
        if(isprime(i))
            cout<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

I have written a simple code to find prime numbers in a given range but I can't get any output although I've written this code many times before but simply can't figure out why I'm getting this kind of error again and again. I have re-written this code 4 times using different loops and programming styles although the logic is same but everything's in vain!

Comment: Step through with a debugger. Get rid of the loop and pick an input you expect to give output, then see where the values of all the variables differ from what you expect.

Comment: Have you tested `isprime` to ensure that it's actually working properly? And have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Which compiler? C or C++?

Comment: `if((n%i)==0)` Won't this always be true for n=1?

Comment: So, either your `cout` is not working or your function `isprime()` never returns `true`. To find out which of these possible reasons is effective: make an unconditional `cout` (a welcome could be nice) to exclude first reason and debug `isprime()` to check for second.

Comment: @J_Kay yeah! that's it! it's working now. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if((n%i)==0)
```

`n` modulo `1` is always zero. Solution:

```
for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if((n%i)==0)
```

Comment: (but i'm not confident in the rest of your implementation)

Comment: As far as I know, only Jon Skeet doesn't make that kind of mistakes (or if He does, the compiler tries to produce the correct binary anyway, no one want to cross Jon Skeet). I certainly do.

Comment: Lol..! thnx for the motivation tho! :p

Comment: The loop should start at 3 and increment by 2.  Even numbers after 2 are not prime.